# Adjusting image properties using MSO prefixes

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, ms-office

> I need to resize an image using Microsoft Office prefixes (MSO)
>   It's important to note that I am unable to use inline styles.

I've already tried the `CSS` and `HTML` versions using `%`,`px` and no specification as shown here:

```
img {
    display: block;
    width: 600;
    height: auto;
}
```

However these have no effect.

I understand that I will most likely need to use the `MSO` prefix instead. Although, I can't seem to find any that will allow me to change the properties of the image.

Expected Result:

> Images are resized once sent to the word document

Actual Result:

> Images are not affected by any styling.

For reference the type of prefix that I'm looking for is exactly the same as:
https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/ac9d052595b406d5a5c1

but simply with the ability to alter images instead of changing font-family etc.
Do you know what I'm missing? Any help is much appreciated.

```
    <!-- /* Style Definitions */
    img {
         height: auto;
         max-width: 8.5in ;
    }
    @page firstSection{
      size:8.5in 11.0in; 
      margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ;
      mso-header-margin:.5in;
      mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;
      }
    -->

    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=documentName.doc" 
    Response.write("<html " & _ 
        "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " & _
        "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" & _ 
        "xmlns='https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/'>") 

    Response.Write "<!--[if mso]>" _
              & "<tr><td style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'>&nbsp;</td><td style='padding:0px;margin:0px;' width='560'>" _
              & "<![endif]-->"

    Response.Write"<!--[if gte mso]><xml><w:WordDocument> 
        <w:View>Print</w:View>" & _
        "<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom><w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/></w:WordDocument></xml>" & _
        "<![endif]-->"

     <body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>
      <div class=Section1>
       <!--Printable Content is added here EG-->
       <img="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png"/>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>

    Response.Write "<!--[if mso]></td><td style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>" _
              & "<td colspan='3' style='padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:20px;height:20px;' height='20'>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>" _
              & "<![endif]-->"
```

Comment: Hi.  In which context are you doing this?  HTML page or???  Can you give us more of your source code so we can reproduce issue.

Comment: Hi there, I'm specifically converting a HTML page into a word document. I'll pop more code in the original post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who is looking for this answer in future the solution is unfortunately an inline style.

`MSO` will not accept `CSS` properties on images. However, you can use the basic `HTML` attributes:

```
width='640' height='400'
```

Which Microsoft Word will actually listen to. The only downside being is that these do have to be in-line.

> Thus, in this scenario I used `Replace()` to edit any `<img style=` tags with: `"<img style= width: 640px;'" width='640'`

This has fixed the majority of my image size formatting issues in word and I hope this answer will prove useful to someone else someday.