# HTML import to Word -> inline image dimensions ignored

Tags: html, image, ms-word, dimensions

When importing an HTML file to Microsoft Word, inline image dimensions are ignored. For example, the following HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
here's an image 50px in height: 
<img height=50 src="data:image/png;base64,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">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

looks like this in a browser:

[image]

but, looks like this in Word (note the huge size relative to the 12-pt font):

[image]

How do I get the image in Word to scale to the correct size? Please note:

- Adding `style="height:50px;width:100px;max-width:100px;max-height:50px;"` to the img tag has no effect on the Word result
- The source image must be inline (`src="data:...` and cannot be saved in a separate file)
- Reducing the dimensions of the encoded data is **not** and option, because the resolution becomes unacceptably low (it won't matter for the image provided in this example, but it will matter a lot for the actual images this is to be used for)

Comment: A good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804561/723299

Comment: @JohnHatton thank you, that provides a partial solution: when `width` and `height` are both explicitly set, they are respected; `width` alone is respected but height retains is original value; `height` alone does not have any effect at all. So this solves the case where we know what the target dimensions are for both `height` and `width`, or when we don't care about keeping scale and know the target width, but leaves open the question of how to solve if we want to only set height (but don't care about proportion), or to only provide height or width (but not both) while retaining proportion

Answer (score 1):

What finally got me a fix was to set the image's spatial resolution (DPI, dots per inch). This was done directly inside the PNG file, before base64-encoding it.

When generating the image output in Python with Pillow, I changed

```py
img.save(buf, format="PNG")
```

to

```py
img.save(buf, format="PNG", dpi=(200,200))
```

Word respected that, at least for PNG images, which is also your case. It may either be ignoring other attributes or just prioritizing the file's DPI setting.